# ASP.NET Web application slowdown in case of multiusers

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis, sql-server-2016

I am facing some major issues in case of multiple concurrent users for my ERP web application. When concurrent user count getting more than 30 my application getting slow. We have developed the web application using ASP.NET ,C#, SQL Server 2016.

What point should I check to getting out from this issue?

Is there any tool/script available using which I can get the overhead in IIS or per page ?

I want to know bandwidth overhead as well.

Answer (score 0):

There can several issue that can cause this issue, 
1. You might want to check the connections are closed after the SQL call.
2. You might have long running queries which can cause dead lock.

You should be able to do the memory dump to see what are the command running when the slow down is happening also you can use sql profiler to see how long it takes to run the queries.